# How I can I get HOST_IP for Docker using docker-machine?

Tags: macos, docker

I just got a new Mac.  My old Mac had a shell script that included these lines:

```
ACTIVE=`docker-machine active 2>/dev/null`
HOST_IP=`docker-machine ip $ACTIVE`
```

When I run this on the new machine it doesn't work.  Just running the docker-machine active command independently I get output like this:

```
No active host found
```

I figured I try to create a default with docker-machine create default, but got this:

```
dial-http tcp 127.0.0.1:49719: unexpected EOF
```

I'm not sure what version of Docker my old Mac was running, but it was native.  New Mac:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:53:38 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:54:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Answer (score 0):

New versions of Docker for Mac no longer user VirtualBox and docker-machine. It's running on xhyve and you can run docker commands very similar to if you were running docker natively on a linux host. There's still a VM under the covers (using moby), but your scripts shouldn't see that anymore. Anything you use to connect to published ports can now connect to localhost as if it is running directly on the Mac host.